# Sorting a listview on calculated data retrieved from database

Tags: android, database, listview, sorting, cursor

I have a list of adverts that is being populated by a custom cursoradapter. I would like for the list to be sorted depending on the distance of the shops location from the user.

I'm having a little trouble implementing this. At the moment, I have the shops location stored in the database as latitude and longitude, I take it out and do some calculations to work out the distance. I currently just output the distance of each shop in each row in the listview, however I would like the listview sorted on the distance, with the nearer adverts shown first. I can't really think how to do this.

I have thought about re-querying the database, however I'm not sure if I could compare my calculated distances to the lat/long fields stored about a certain shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first we need to calculate the distance using Haversine formula from the current user position and the destination coordinate, then we need to store the calculated distance in the database . finally we can query the database with distance in ascending order.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I already use the Haversine formula to calculate the distance. Do you have any suggestions how we would store the calculated distance? I know the code to do it, but I mean would it go into a new database specifically for distances or one of the existing ones. I currently have shop (that has the lat and long) and also advert, as one shop can have multiple adverts. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've now done it so it stores the distance to the advert database and it works perfectly.